# Help creating a simple C shell

Tags: c, shell

I am new to C and I am trying to create a simple C shell that will allow the user to perform various functions like chdir, cd, exit, mkdir.

I've posted my code below.  Can anyone look through it and see what I am doing wrong?  I am not sure if I am using `fork` and `execcv` correctly. Thanks!

```
include stdio.h
include stdlib.h
include unistd.h
include <string.h>
include sys/types.h

main() {
    //char *user;

    //if ((user = getlogin()) == NULL)
    //    perror("__getlogin1() error");
    //else printf("__getlogin1() returned %s\n", user);
    int j, status;
    int pid, c_pid;
    int i = 0;
    char *tmp, **ap;
    char instring[80]; // store one line of input
    char *argv[10]; // store parameters in the format for execv()

    promptstart:

    printf("Please enter a commcand:\n");

    // read a char at a time and put it in instring[]
    // put a '\0' at the end
    instring[i] = getc(stdin); // stdin is the keyboard
    while (instring[i] != '\n') {
        i++;
        instring[i] = getc(stdin);
    }
    instring[i] = '\0'; // replace '\n' with '\0'

    tmp = instring;
    i = 0;
    argv[i] = strsep(&tmp, " \t"); // put first word int argv[0]
    while ((i < 10) && (argv[i] != '\0')) {
        i++;
        argv[i] = strsep(&tmp, " \t");
    }

    // print out the command and options.
    i = 0;
    while (argv[i] != '\0') {
        printf("your entered: %s\n", argv[i++]);
    }

    //PLACE ERROR HERE

    if ((c_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            printf("child (%d) prints %d\n", getpid(), j);
        exit(0);
    } else if (c_pid > 0) {
        c_pid = wait(&status);
        printf("child %d exited with status %d\n", c_pid, status);
    } else {
        execvp(argv[0], argv);

    }
    goto promptstart;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the behavior is?

Comment: Well it runs and loops through back to prompt I just dont think its executing the commands.

Comment: First, your formatting an indenting is horribly inconsistent, which makes it difficult to read the code.  Second, what do you mean, "what am I doing wrong?"? What doesn't work?  What do you expect, and what do you actually get?  Fer heck's sake, you don't even tell us if its a compile-time/link-time/run-time error!  We do not debug-via-ESP.

Comment: edit your Question to include more information.  Do not put your responses in comments.

Comment: You probably want   execvp(argv[0], &argv[1]);  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least IMO, you're putting far too much into `main`. I'd start with something like:

```
int main() { 
    char input[128];

    do { 
        fgets(stdin, input, sizeof(input));
        dispatch(input);
    } while (strcmp(input, "exit"));
    return 0;
}
```

Then `dispatch` will look for internal commands, and only do an `exec` when/if it's given a command it doesn't recognize. To keep things simple to start with, you might consider using `popen` to execute external commands, and leave switching to a "raw" fork/exec for later, when the limitations of `popen` start to cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

For shell builtins (`man bash`), you probably don't want to fork/exec. I would save fork/exec for running programs that are in your PATH (an environment variable that your shell will have to manage). The shell itself should interface with the filesystem through commands like `chdir` (`man 2 chdir`).

Consider using a nice string tokenizer (or just fallback to strtok) for parsing the commandline, and as another comment suggests, abstract that into a function so that your main loop is lean.